# Speed up loading and drawing multi images in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently have a problem with loading images and draw in canvas. In localhost , it work smoothly but when put to my web server it not work as smooth as localhost at all. I need to refresh page two to tree time then it work. So is there alternative ways to deal with this. The following is my sample code

```
function action1() {
 var imgObj = new Image()
 timer = setInterval(function(){
         imgObj.src = 'img/velOpen/' + (index++) + '.png';
         imgObj.onload = function(){
                 context.clearRect(0,0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
                 context.drawImage(imgObj, X, y);   
         }
        },100);
};
```

Note: I have serval images with size of only 32 kb

Comment: Maybe load the images once at page load, and really only do drawing in the function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until all images are loaded before you start drawing to the canvas.

Here's an example of how to call a function immediately after the last image loads.

```
function loadImageGroup(urls, onCompleteFunc) {
    var numImagesNotYetLoaded = urls.length;
    var urlToImageMap = {};    
    var markLoaded = function() {
        if (--numImagesNotYetLoaded == 0)
            onCompleteFunc(urlToImageMap);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = markLoaded;
        img.src = urls[i];
        urlToImageMap[urls[i]] = img;
    }
}
var urls = [
    'http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'
  , 'http://www.google.com/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png'
];
loadImageGroup(urls, function(urlToImageMap) {
    //all are loaded. draw to canvas here
    var imgObject = urlToImageMap['http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'];
    alert(imgObject.width)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vHwKr/1/

That's just a sample. I say that because it's not totally robust. Imagine if an image failed to load for some reason - the on complete function would never be called. Maybe you would want a timeout or something...